# Hide child grid when adding new main item

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a grid that has child grid for each item, when i add a new item to the main grid, there is a stub for the child (with the toolbar etc and an empty grid for the child), I would like to hide the child grid when adding new one, i know i need the edit event, i just dont know how to get reference to the detailgrid for the item that the row was just created for input.

edit event has e.sender, e.container, e.model, first 2 reference the main grid of course as the event is raised by the main grid

Answer (score 0):

The required behavior is not supported out of the box, however you can for example attach click event handler to the expanding arrows in the Grid. In the event handler you can prevent the expanding if current model is new. Please check the example below:

```
//Change Employees with your grid name
//the grid should have model ID defined
$("#Employees table").on("click", ".k-hierarchy-cell a", function (e) {
dataItem = $("#Employees").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(e.srcElement).closest("tr"));
//check if is new record
if (dataItem.isNew()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
})
```

**UPDATE (as requested):** The above code should be executed in script tag (wrapped in document "ready" event handler) which is placed just after the Grid initialization code.

Comment: where would i put this code? putting it in the edit event handler does not work because the code is not wired first edit, putting it in the anonymous jquery method does fire the event, however e.srcElement is null hence dataItem is always null, I have changed the id to my own of course

Comment: where would i put this code? putting it in the edit event handler does not work because the code is not wired first edit, putting it in the anonymous jquery method does fire the event, however e.srcElement is null hence dataItem is always null, I have changed the id to my own of course. Also i have the model id wired up